# Installing Coveo Enterprise Search 7.0 throwing COM Error

Tags: coveo

I have installed and configured Enterprise Coveo Search as per documentation and after installing Coveo for Sitecore, when I browse the diagnostic page I am facing the issue below:
[image]

I have tried connecting to CES, but couldn't.

[image]

AdminService is working as expected

**Update Added Showconfig**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the showconfig output you got, specially the section with the tags adminServiceUri and cesMasterInformation?

Comment: @Diego Updated question as per your comments.The username and password section is blank as admin service doesn't require the same.

Comment: this looks right. One other thing you might want to check is whether all coveo services are running fine specially Coveo Enterprise Search. Looks like the coveo admin service is running fine. 
Also just in case make sure the user running those services have proper permissions. 
Also do you see any errors on the Windows Event Viewer? Last but not least which Sitecore and Coveo for Sitecore versions you have?

Comment: All services running fine. Sitecore Version 8.2 update 1 and Coveo for Sitecore 82 4.0 (1329)

Answer (score 2):

**1** small mistake in the installation and it ruined all day. So, this is the issue:

When you install Sitecore package, at one stage it's ask for **secret key** for your REST endpoint.

*You must provide the `application secret key` in `config.yml` at **C:\Program Files\Coveo Search API 8** (depends on your COVEO Search API  Installation folder).*

I have **mistakenly** generated new key instead of following above step which caused communication issue.

[image]